# What is the proper way to add a jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces, ajax4jsf

I am using JBOSS 3.01 and JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.

What is the proper way to add a jquery plugin?

```
<a:loadScript src="/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"/>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

I get 
jQuery.cookie is not a function
[Break On This Error] if(jQuery.cookie("cssswitch")) { 
When I try to use the a:loadScript. Our namespace is a: instead of a4j:

Comment: Can you please let me know from where can I get the JQUery plugin for JSF1.2 and RF3.3...jquery website is not providing any plugins as of now..can you help me out..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

ite a basic html element which doesn't need other interpreter .

Comment: Thanks, I am going to try that!