# how to include Jquery or javascript file to primefaces 3.5

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have some Jquery plugins to add to my JSF page but they don't work. I integrated them with this syntax:

```
<h:outputScript name="/js/ui3.js"  />
```

Is there any solution to include those files, especialy my plugin file ui3.js, because it's simple javascript that have traitement.

ui3.js

```
$( init ); 
   function init() {
      (function($){
         var sortOpts = {
         connectWith: ["#sortablesA", "#sortablesB"]
      };
      $("#sortablesA, #sortablesB").sortable(sortOpts);
   })(jQuery);
}
```

**Update :**

**Problem resolved**

The solution is: you need just add `//<![CDATA[ //]]>` to your javascript or jquery file and call it normaly with  in your JSF page after the head or in the head.

example.js

```
//<![CDATA[ 
 $( init ); 
    function init() {
       (function($){
          var sortOpts = {
             connectWith: ["#sortablesA", "#sortablesB"]
          };
          $("#sortablesA, #sortablesB").sortable(sortOpts);
       })(jQuery);
    }
//]]>
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173441/what-is-the-proper-way-to-add-a-jquery-plugin

Comment: @BalusC: i deleted the Jquery libs and i keeped the UI3.js .  with out //<![CDATA[    //]]> you cant incluse a JS file with Primefaces.

Comment: i know that jquery existe in primefaces thats why i modified my post and deleted adding jquery.js and jquery-ui.js but i keeped the ui3.js that have special function. thats the helpfull side in my post